# How to generate data from a table to another table?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a table in database called Employee which has 4 columns namely

- EmployeeID    EmployeeName    Designation   Reporting Manager

which gets updated with new details everytime a new record is added in aspx page.
EXAMPLE:

```
EID     EMPLOYEE_NAME     DESIGNATION       REPORTING_MANAGER
1        TIM COOK            CEO                   Null
2        MILLER              CTO                   TIM COOK
3        BRAD                COO                   TIM COOK
4        WILLIAM             HRD                   TIM COOK
5        JOHN                TECH MANAGER(DEV)     WILLIAM
6        WALLACE             TECH MANAGER(TEST)    WILLIAM
7        SUNDAR              SWIFT DEV             JOHN
8        PETER               SWIFT DEV             JOHN
9        STEVE               TEST ENGINEER         WALLACE
```

I want to generate data in table2 from above table(table1) like the one below,

```
EID     EMPLOYEE_NAME      REPORTING_MANAGER_ID
1        TIM COOK          Null
2        MILLER            1
3        BRAD              1
4        WILLIAM           1
5        JOHN              4
6        WALLACE           4
7        SUNDAR            5
8        PETER             5
9        STEVE             6
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT T1.EID,
       T1.EMPLOYEE_NAME,
       T1.DESIGNATION,
       T1.REPORTING_MANAGER,
       T2.EID AS REPORTING_MANAGER_ID
FROM   EMPLOYEE T1
       LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE T2
              ON T1.EMPLOYEE_NAME = T2.REPORTING_MANAGER
```

Answer (score 1):

**Simple:**

1. Create a stored procedure to insert data into Table2 from Table1 with a LEFT JOIN to insert/update rows in Table2 which are not present in Table1.
2. Call this stored procedure after new details is inserted (I'm assuming the insert or update in Table1 is through a stored procedure)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a number of ways.

With a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT e.EID ,
       e.EMPLOYEE_NAME ,
       e.DESIGNATION ,
       e.REPORTING_MANAGER,
       rm.EID AS REPORTING_MANAGER_ID
FROM Employee e
LEFT JOIN Employee rm ON  rm.EMPLOYEE_NAME = e.REPORTING_MANAGER
```

Subquery route:

```
SELECT e.EID ,
       e.EMPLOYEE_NAME ,
       e.DESIGNATION ,
       e.REPORTING_MANAGER,
       (SELECT TOP 1 rm.EID 
        FROM Employee rm 
        WHERE rm.EMPLOYEE_NAME = e.REPORTING_MANAGER) AS REPORTING_MANAGER_ID
FROM Employee e
```

Comment: Thanks Tanner for the help.